# div with same horizontal position

Tags: html, css, asp.net, stylesheet

I have a page and two div. They should appear with same top position but they are appearing with different vertical rows.

One comes with different vertical position and other appears with different vertical position.

Why they are not having same horizontally

following is the html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs"    Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="f1" runat="server">
<div style="margin-left:100px; top:10px; border-width:10px; width:400px; border-style:solid;">
fawad
</div>
<div style="margin-left:600px; top:10px; border-width:10px; width:200px; border-style:solid">ali</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Since most who can help you don't use ASP, please always supply the generated HTML and not the markup with the generated HTML. In addition, your doctype is for web pages that were transitioning to the then new version of (X)HTML back in 1999. Such a doctype should not have been used for new web pages since then. I suggest you use the current doctype <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

The `top` CSS style does not work the way you think it does. You may want to use a `float` instead, however, if you want a simpler fix, try this:

```
<form id="f1" runat="server" style="position: relative">
<div style="top:10px; border-width:10px; width:400px; border-style:solid; position: absolute; left: 0">
fawad
</div>
<div style="top:10px; border-width:10px; width:200px; border-style:solid; position: absolute; left: 420px">ali</div>
</form>
```

The CSS box model is extremely complicated, but well worth learning if you do a lot of web work. `float`s  work like this:

```
<div style="float: left">fawad</div>
<div>ali</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of margin-left value given to your 2nd div ..

Just remove the margin left value of your 2nd div and add this to your css :

```
div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

So your Html will look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="f1" runat="server">
<div style="margin-left:100px; top:10px; border-width:10px; width:400px; border-style:solid;">
fawad
</div>
<div style="top:10px; border-width:10px; width:200px; border-style:solid">ali</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position must be given if you are giving top. I can see in your code position is not given to div.

I have corrected your HTML code. Please take a look at the code given below. It is working fine and fulfilling your requirement.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="f1" runat="server">
<div style="margin-left:100px; position:absolute;top:10px; border-width:10px; width:400px; border-style:solid;">
fawad
</div>
<div style="margin-left:600px; position:absolute;top:10px; border-width:10px; width:200px; border-style:solid">ali</div>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second div has too much margin, so it overflows the container and drops to the next available space. 
Also I believe without setting explicit margin left and right value, whatever doesn't get set, will fill the rest of the container.

```
<form id="f1" runat="server">
<div style="margin-left:100px; top:10px; border-width:10px; width:400px; border-style:solid;display:inline-block">
fawad
</div>
<div style="margin-left:100px; top:10px; border-width:10px; width:200px; border-     style:solid;display:inline-block">ali</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was

```
display:inline-block
```

Nothing more nothing less